# Count Length of Digits Per Column Per Row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, variable-length

I generated the following table:

```
CREATE table user (  
    user_id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    user_phone_number INT,  
    user_city VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

And I'm being asked the following: number of users per length of the phone number (number of numeric digits)

I try the following:

```
SELECT LENGTH(user_phone_number)
FROM user
WHERE user is not null
GROUP BY user_phone_number);
```

but if there are several users with the same phone number length it repeats them in several rows instead of providing the Total per length. Please help

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems with your SQL.  The most obvious is that you have left out the `COUNT()`.  This is important if you want to count something.

The second is that the `SELECT` column and the `GROUP BY` column don't match.  These should (almost always) be the same:

```
SELECT LENGTH(user_phone_number), COUNT(*)
FROM user
WHERE user_phone_number is not null
GROUP BY LENGTH(user_phone_number);
```

You probably want an `ORDER BY LENGTH(user_phone_number)` at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem, I just changed the WHERE user for a WHERE user_phone_number.